# How to simple deep nested route in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a trouble routing with `nuxt`.

For example I have `url` like this `www.example.com/slug1/slug2/slug3/slug4`.

On basic `nuxt` routing, it should be like this in the folder:

```
pages //main page
  _slug1 //folder fol slug1
   index.vue //index for slug1
   _slug2 //folder for slug2
    index.vue //index for slug2
    _slug3 //folder for slug3
     index.vue //index for slug3
     _slug4 //folder for slug4
      index.vue //index for slug4
```

Is there a simple way? For example just 1 folder for all that routes?

```
pages
  _slug //folder for all slug (slug1, slug2, slug3 and slug4)
```

Comment: Why do you want to change that?

Comment: make it simple, easy for maintenance and basically i have same page/format for all of that slug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can use the [Unknown dynamic nested routes](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes) feature to achieve that. Basically, add a `pages/_.vue` file and fetch the correct content based on the path.

Comment: Thanks! The link is outdated though. It is now https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes